# Will you be the first to get free?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, grid-deduction, reachability, lights-out

It is your first day in prison and you are approached by a guard having a hunch for puzzles.

He tells you that he gives every new prisoner the chance to be freed if they can present him with a version of his favorite puzzle that he can not solve. He proudly informs you that no one has gotten out so far; he
is just too good.

The puzzle requires the prisoner to arrange $9$ coins in a $3 \times 3$ grid with heads or tails up by his choosing.
The guard will then try to find a way to turn all coins to head until the next day. But he is only allowed
to turn coins in a slected $2 \times 2$ square or vertical/horizontal line, not only single coins.

After he explained the puzzle to you, he confidently adds
*"And you know what? Starting today, I will beat everyone without turning any middle lines."*
You smile and gladly agree to the challenge, with the burning question in mind:

*Will I really be the first one to get out?*

Comment: "Will I really be the first one to get out?" - no, because this guard is obviously messing with you. He wants to get your hopes up and then laugh in your face at how gullible you are.

Comment: Is the "middle line rule" an actual rule, or is he allowed to break that since it's just his boasting, and not a part of the actual rule set?

Comment: @Vilx- No he will stick to it and not turn any coins along the middle line. I changed the text to hopefully make this more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

> Let $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_8$ denote the $8$ possible moves that the guard may use ($4$ squares and the $4$ outer lines). Consider the moves as group actions on the set of grids. Since $v_i^2 = e$ and $v_i v_j = v_j v_i,$ there are at most $2^8 = 256$ grids reachable from one where all coins are heads. There are $2^9 = 512$ grids in total, so there exists at least $256$ for which the guard will fail. To make this solution constructive, you may enumerate the valid grids and choose one that doesn't appear in the list.

Explicit Grid

> The grid where the bottom left corner is tails and everything else is heads is not solvable. If it is, then there is a sequence of moves to flip this corner. By symmetry, there is a sequence of moves to flip any corner, and combining with a move flipping an outer line, there is a sequence of moves to flip any of the outer $8$ squares. Combining with a $2 \times 2$ square, there is a sequence of moves to flip any square, hence any position is reachable, contradiction. In fact, there are exactly $256$ reachable positions since the vectors representing each move are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_2:$ [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C+%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%7D%7D)

Comment: The reasoning and conclusion are correct! However it does not yet answer the formulated question completely. And you will get bonus credit for describing a grid which he can not solve ;)

Comment: @Nemo I have found a grid that works, but you may not like the way I proved it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nemo - I liked FlorianF's answer better. :)

Comment: @Vilx- His answer is not complete yet ;)

Comment: @Nemo - Oh, come on! :D

Answer (score 16):

There is a simple solution.

> Turn all the coins to tails.  This will set you free.

Because

> Consider the coins marked with X.
>     `X . X`
>     `. X .`
>     `X . X`
>
>   Every move reverses exactly 2 of these coins.
>   Since you start with an odd number of tails among the X's, the number of tails will remain odd whatever the guard does.
>   So it is impossible for him to reach zero tails.
>
>  PS: Note that aschepler also came to the conclusion that corners plus center parity is the problem, in a more systematic analysis of the question.
>   I just showed it is A problem.  And that is enough I think.

Answer (score 5):

Adding some findings to [the answer by Display name](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101163).

As already noted,

> the effects of different sequences of moves form a commutative group generated by the original 8 moves, which all have order 2, so this group of grid actions cannot be larger than $2^8$, and cannot reach the desired coin state from all $2^9$ possible coin states.

Call the coin positions

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and label the guard's moves with digits for the flipped coins, e.g. {147} and {2356}.

The guard has sequences of moves which can:

> Flip the coin in the middle of any edge, leaving the other 8 in their same states.

> To flip coin $2$, do {4578} {5689} {147} {369} {123}. The others are possible by rotating this pattern.

and sequences which can:

> Flip any corner coin and the center coin, leaving the other 7 in their same states.

> To flip coins $1$ and $5$, do {369} {789} {2356} {4578} {1245}. The others are possible by rotating this pattern.

By combining these sequences, the guard can solve any initial position where:

> the number of center and corner coins showing heads is odd. This gives $2^8$ solvable positions, and as mentioned above, there cannot be any more solvable positions, so this is a necessary and sufficient condition on solvable puzzles.

Though it seems strange that

> nobody has won before, since anyone just placing randomly would have a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance of creating an impossible puzzle. Maybe the part about not using middle rows is new, if the guard got too confident.

Comment: In fact, we can skip all of the group theory now. Each move does not change the parity of $T,$ the total number of center and corner coins showing heads, so only the $256$ positions where $T$ is odd are candidates for reachable positions. And the moves you gave can reach any of these candidates.

Comment: This gives the full solution! About the last comment: Yes, he has gotten to confident.

Comment: @Displayname Ah right, that's a simpler way to see the other states aren't solvable.